# Map value from one column into another in separate tables using Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

Given the following `one-to-many` relationship (One `Receipt` has many `LineItem`'s), I would like to map the `Price` field from the `Receipt` table into the `Price` field of `LineItem` table (for each `LineItem` in `Product`).

**Receipt Schema**

```golang
type Product struct {
    ID             uint       `json:"id"`
    TotalPrice     float64    `json:"total"`
    LineItems      []LineItem `json:"lineItems"`
}
```

**LineItem Schema**

```golang
type LineItem struct {
    ID          uint    `json:"id"`
    ProductID   uint    `json:"productID"`
    Price       float64 `json:"price"`
}
```

I'm currently using [gorm](http://gorm.io/), an ORM for Go, but I can't find the functionality to support what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't see the sense in what you're trying to do. How does the product price relate (conceptually) to the line item price?

Comment: Think of this like a receipt from a grocery store - if you purchase one loaf of bread and one bag of milk, there will be two line items on your receipt. One should show "1 Bread @ $1.99" and the other "1 Milk @ 3.99". I would like to populate the `Price` inside a `LineItem` with the pre-defined `Price` from a `Product` essentially.

Comment: Do you need to store the price in two places? In a database we strive to normalise data such that each piece of truth is stored in one place. You already have the productID foreign key in your line item. Isn't that enough for you to use a join in your query and retrieve the price? `SELECT LineItem.*, Product.Price FROM LineItem JOIN Product ON LineItem.ProductID = Product.ID`

Comment: Ideally we don't need to store the price in both tables - I was trying to find if gorm had a feature that didn't have me manually writing SQL but it looks like I will have to - I'll try out that statement!

Comment: @Sean seems like you have typo here. The first struct, is it `Product` or should it be `Receipt`?

Comment: @har07 I updated the naming in the original example for clarity shortly after Matt responded

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't answer my question. I assumed it should be `Receipt` then, and you have another model `Product` which isn't posted in the question. See my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have 3 tables/models, `Receipt`, `Product`, and `LineItem`, you can add field that reference `Product` in `LineItem` model like so :

```
type Receipt struct {
    ID             uint       `json:"id"`
    TotalPrice     float64    `json:"total"`
    LineItems      []LineItem `json:"lineItems"`
}

type Product struct {
    ID          uint    `json:"id"`
    Price       float64 `json:"price"`
}

type LineItem struct {
    ID          uint     `json:"id"`
    ProductID   uint     `json:"productID"`
    Product     *Product `json:"product"`
}
```

Then you can query `Receipt` while populating `LineItems` field as well as `Product` field in each `LineItem` by using gorm's [`Preload`](http://gorm.io/docs/preload.html) feature:

```
db.Preload("LineItems").Preload("LineItems.Product").Find(&receipt)
```

This way you will have the price info in each `LineItem` accessible through `Product` field:

```
for _, li in receipt.LineItems {
    fmt.Println(li.Product.Price)
}
```